# Pattern matching with string in Erlang. Variable in left position

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

With Erlang I can do something like this:

```
"kapa" ++ D = "kapagama". % D now has a value "gama"
```

Is there a way to put the "variable" in left position? Something like

```
D ++ "gama" = "anyLengthStringgama".
```

For this expression shell returns an error:

```
* 1: illegal pattern
```

**Bonus question:** Can somebody explain why it doesn't work? What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you should either use [regular expression matching](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html), or use a couple of list reversals:

```
1> "amag" ++ D = lists:reverse("anyLengthStringgama").
"amaggnirtShtgneLyna"
2> lists:reverse(D).
"anyLengthString"
```

Answer (score 18):

```
"kapa" ++ D = "kapagama".
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
[$k, $a, $p, $a | D] = "kapagama".
```

and this is just syntactic sugar for

```
[$k|[$a|[$p|[$a|D]]]] = "kapagama".
```

There is not any counterpart for this code:

```
D ++ "gama" = "kapagama".
```

which this can be syntactic sugar for. So as Steve Vinoski wrote, you have to do use `lists:reverse/1`

```
"amag" ++ D = lists:reverse("kapagama"), lists:reverse(D).
```

or use `re` module.

Comment: The reason for this is that pattern matching cannot **search**, it can only match against explicit patterns. `D ++ "gama"` is basically saying search down the string until you find a `"gama"` at the end then return everything before it, which doesn't work.

Comment: @rvirding Can one define such operators though? I mean a search-powered pattern? Probably not in Erlang?

Comment: @NaderGhanbari No you cannot define your own operators. The reason why you cannot match against `D ++ gama` is that would need to search to find the end and then check. Pattern matching just does straight forward matching.